# How to mark the default row to select in a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design

To start off, I have the following tables:

- `products` - a list of products
- `images` - a list of images (which may or may not belong to a product)
- `product_images` - a join table to connect products to images (this table just has `id`, `product_id`, and `image_id`)

I need a way to mark one image as the default image to use for a product, but I'm not quite sure how to set it up. I've thought of a few options but none of them feel correct.

Options I've thought of:

1. Add an `image_id` field to the `products` table for the default image. This seems bad cause the image on the product might not be an image that belongs to that product (I could take care of this on the application side, but I'm looking for more elegant solutions)
2. Add a column on the `product_images` table that marks that image as default, and add a unique constraint on the combined `product_id` field and `default` field (the `product_images` table would then look like: `id`, `product_id`, `image_id`, `default`). I've never used unique constraints before, and I'm not sure if they're the right way to go.

Hope you guys have some better advice!

Comment: `id` is unnecessary (and inefficient) in a mapping table; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: `UNIQUE(prod_id, img_id, default)` will not achieve your purpose.

Comment: @RickJames You're right. I was initially planning on including another table called `product_default_images` which just had the `id` of the row on the `product_images` table (so I needed the `id`).

Comment: Do you guys think having a table called `product_default_images` which holds the `id` of the `product_images` table is overkill? I'd still need to have application level logic to make sure there aren't multiple entries per product.

Comment: Not unreasonable.  (One might argue that there is some redundancy.)  Go ahead and try it.  In any new database app, plan on major design changes, including schema changes, a few months into the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UNIQUE constraint on (product_id, default) won't work since you can have several images that are not default for each product. A similar approach is to add a display_order attribute:

```
CREATE TABLE product_images
( product_id ... NOT NULL
      references ...
, image_id ... NOT NULL
      references ...
, display_order SMALLINT NOT NULL
,     PRIMARY KEY (product_id, display_order) )
```

To get the default image for a product choose the one with the smallest display_order for that product.

Depending on your business requirements you may add an alternative key. Examples:

```
-- An image may not be reused between products
ALTER TABLE product_images ADD CONSTRAINT ...
    UNIQUE (image_id)

-- An image may not be used several times for each product
ALTER TABLE product_images ADD CONSTRAINT ...
    UNIQUE (image_id, product_id)
```

To get the default image for a product:

```
SELECT image_id
FROM product_images
WHERE product_id = ?
ORDER BY display_order
LIMIT 1;
```

EDIT: I keep forgetting this bug in MySQL ...

To assign a new default image for a product:

```
UPDATE product_images x     
    SET display_order = (SELECT min from (SELECT MIN(display_order)-1 as min                                        FROM product_images                          
                                          WHERE product_id = ?) as y)
WHERE product_id = ?   
  AND image_id = ?;
```

or possibly:

```
UPDATE product_images x     
    SET display_order = (SELECT min 
                         FROM (
                             SELECT display_order-1 as min                         
                             FROM product_images                          
                             WHERE product_id = ? 
                             ORDER BY display_order LIMIT 1
                         ) as y
                        ) 
WHERE product_id = ?
  AND image_id = ?;
```

Comment: This would cover it, but would require application level maintenance. Do you have an ideas for solutions that don't require extras on the application side?

Comment: What do you mean with application level maintenance?

Comment: As in, I have to update the display_order field on the application side for all images whenever I make a change to the which image is the default image. Do you have any ideas for a solution where I can just edit the old default and new default and nothing else?

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: Ah, so you just assign a lower number than all the existing ones instead of renumbering the entire list. Might lead to integer overflow, but for my use case that'll never happen. Works for me, thanks!

Comment: Yes, the number itself has no meaning, it is just an ordering. As for overflow you could have a periodic job that checks if you reached say 80%. This will give you time to plan for maintenance.